# ASP MVC4 null model passed to action in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I wonder why i get null model passing from the view to the controller.

Here is my code in the view (UpdatePersonal.cshtml):

```
@model Project.Models.UserInfo

@using (Html.BeginForm()){
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.userinfo.firstname);
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.userinfo.firstname, new { @Value = ViewBag.Firstname });

   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.userinfo.lastname);
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.userinfo.lastname, new { @Value = ViewBag.Lastname });

   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.userinfo.email);
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.userinfo.email, new { @Value = ViewBag.Email });

   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.userinfo.phone);
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.userinfo.phone, new { @Value = ViewBag.Phone });

   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.username, new { @Value = ViewBag.Username });

   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />}
```

Here is the action method that accepts it:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult UpdatePersonal(UserInfo userInfo){
    //some code here
    //my breakpoint}
```

i see the model being passed has null value as i used breakpoint

my model:

```
public class UserInfo
{
    [BsonId]
    public string username { get; set; }
    public Info userinfo { get; set; }
    public Address address { get; set; }


    public class Info
    {
        public string firstname { get; set; }
        public string lastname { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public string street { get; set; }
        public string address1 { get; set; }
        public string address2 { get; set; }
        public string postalcode { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: is your action decorated with `[HttpPost]`?

Comment: yes, i have the [HttpPost] in the action

Comment: What does your model look like?

Comment: @beautifulcoder i editted it.

Comment: Delete "new { @Value = ViewBag.XXX }" for each textboxfor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my problem, instead i used and pass the subclass

```
@model Buch_Ankauf.Models.UserInfo.Info

@using (Html.BeginForm()){

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.firstname);
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.firstname, new { @Value = ViewBag.Firstname });

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.lastname);
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.lastname, new { @Value = ViewBag.Lastname });

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.email);
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.email, new { @Value = ViewBag.Email });

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.phone);
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.phone, new { @Value = ViewBag.Phone });

@Html.Hidden("username", new { @Value = ViewBag.Username });

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />}
```

in my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult UpdatePersonal(UserInfo.Info userInfo)
    {
```

Comment: jbbi answer is the correct solution. You cannot name the parameter of the POST method with the same name as one of your model properties. And as stated in the comments - do NOT try to override the value attribute using `new { @Value = ViewBag.someValue }`

Answer (score 2):

You work around the problem but your first code was good, the only problem was the name of your action method param was the same that the name of your model property.

Change your action method signature for example by :

```
public ActionResult UpdatePersonal(UserInfo info)
```

and it should be work !

Comment: hi, i tried your suggestion but same thing occur. Still null.